# why the summation is zero inside the parenthesis of this formula

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a question. I don't really understand why

$$\sum_{j=1}^n \left(A\hat{e}_j - \sum_{i=1}^n a_{ij} \hat{e}_i\right) v_j = 0$$

for any vector $\vec{v}$
would imply that the coefficient inside the above formula would vanish, i.e:

$$A\hat{e}_j = \sum_{i=1}^n a_{ij}\hat{e}_i$$

My question is: I don't really understand why the first formula equal to zero for all $v_j$ (these are the coefficient of the vector $V$) would imply that the coefficient inside the parenthesis will become zero too, if the first equation holds for any vector.

Could someone kindly explain to me.

Thank you.

Comment: Don't use latex code as code. Simply type the latex things in the text and we will see it rendered. I can't actually read what you are asking for

Comment: Welcome to MathSE!
See [this guide](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for how to mark up math nicely on this site.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Consider what happens when $v = \hat{e}_k$ for each $k = 1,\ldots,n$?

Comment: Hi, I know the dot product of \hat{e_k} with e_i where i not equal k will be zero. But I am not sure how to see the "sum" (i.e the second expression) in my question will equal to zero.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is since the expression (i.e. the second expression in my question) dot product with any vector v will be zero, then it must means that it is perpendicular to every vector in the vector space. So that's why this vector (i.e. the second expression) has to be a zero vector. But I am not sure if this is the correct thinking. Also I rather have an algebraic proof. Probably my reasoning is correct, but I want to see something algebraic, or something related to linear algebra.

Comment: I just want a concrete answer. But I still don't know how.